# Normalize a sinusoidal wave to a fixed voltage

Tags: filter, signal-processing, waveform

As input I have got a sinusoidal wave of variable amplitude (Vin). This amplitude can be whatever between 0.5 V to 5 V for example.

I want to normalize this input to a fixed sinwave with amplitude Vout, for example 10 V.

In other words: I get a sinewave as input of random voltage and I want to output a sinewave of amplitude 10 V and that has the same frequency as the sinewave of input.

Example:
Sinwave input: 1 V and 50 Hz.
Sinwave output: 10 V and 50 Hz.

If I change sinwave Input to 5 V and 50 Hz, the output stays the same at 10 V and 50 Hz.

If possible I would like to use only analog components.

Thanks

Comment: It seems a job for the automatic gain control AGC.

Comment: You could amplify the sine wave into saturation until it becomes a square wave  (or use a comparator) then filter it back down into a sine wave (or some other method that generates sine waves from square waves since filtering would have trouble always getting rid of the 3rd harmonics a wide enough a frequency range). Or a PLL.

Comment: What is the range of allowed input frequencies?

Comment: sounds like a classical XY-problem... answer the question "why do you think you need to do this?"... i.e. what are you actually trying to accomplish,  don't presume a solution and you'll get better answers

Comment: Something like this perhaps ? https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/AN_934.pdf

Comment: If the input wave is clean, or can be filtered to the point that it is clean, you could just use a comparator to create a 10V square wave. Then filter the square wave to make it more sinusoidal.

Comment: The XY-comment above should be taken seriously. Those of us who have hanged around some time have learned that often the question asks something which actually is useless for the actual problem. The questioner doesn't want to reveal his original problem X. He has in silence made a nonsense assumption that trick Y would solve X. So he asks how to do Y. He may get answers but they are useless. Sometimes the real goal is revealed after the questioner has noticed that none of the given answers fits, no matter they can be perfect for Y.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Sounds like I have some material to start drafting a solution. And for the XY commenters: you can chill your XY rethoric as my question is purely theoretical. I am not trying to solve anything. Just curious about possible solution to this scenario. That’s it.

Comment: Please don't belittle or mock the XY commenters - they're correct. It's more than reasonable for people to want valid and justified reasons from you for your question before they put their valuable time and effort into any answers. The site's not a free engineering helpline, please respect the work that they put in. Thanks.

Comment: @Markhaus Ehhhh...doesn't sound very theoretical if you're trying to draft a solution and have a scenario. What it sounds like is you really need is a measurement of frequency of an incoming sine wave then do "something" with that information, rather than to change its amplitude. Because the strange way your question is framed implies you don't care about anything in the sine-wave other than its frequency. It's that framing that makes it sound like an XY problem.

Comment: You might not have noticed but my proposal above measures the frequency of the sine-wave, throws everything else away, and reconstructs a new sine wave. It doesn't actually do what you specifically asked for.

Comment: I do really appreciate the time spent and quickness of the responses. That is what I enjoy of this site. Only wanted to specify the pure theoretical nature of my question. I hoped in something more elegant and simple than AGC (like an op amp amplifying to a reference voltage) but it seems that is the only way. I got some luck with an LC feedback in a non inverting amplifier, but still very dependent on input amplitude and works only around LC resonant frequencies.

Comment: *I would like to use only analog components* - doesn't sound like a very theoretical exercise to me.

Comment: This was because I am studying analog components and if we go digital of course there are trillions of ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can do it with only analog components. Which method is most appropriate depends on what information in the signal you want to preserve:-

- Amplitude: You want to discard it and fix the output at 10 V.
- Frequency: ...must be exactly preserved, or not? What input frequency variation must it handle?
- Phase: What short and long term variation is allowed? How much phase noise can you tolerate?
- Purity: how much distortion is acceptable? Must the output waveform follow the input exactly even if it is not a pure sine wave?

The obvious way to keep the output amplitude constant is to add a 'volume' or 'gain' control. This could be a potentiometer or a [Voltage Controlled Amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-gain_amplifier) (VCA). There are two ways of controlling this:-

1. 'Servo loop': Measure output amplitude - if it is higher than the desired voltage then reduce the gain, if lower then increase it.
2. [Feed forward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feed_forward_(control)): Measure amplitude at the input and adjust volume or gain to the amount that you 'know' will produce the required output level.

Simplest way to do this? Put a knob on the volume control and watch the level on a meter, twisting the knob as needed to keep the output at 10 V. But perhaps you want the circuit to do it automatically, in which case *it* will have to monitor the signal amplitude and adjust the volume or gain, by eg. operating a motorized potentiometer or adjusting the control voltage on a VCA.

These methods have their problems. A physical pot has excellent linearity, but very slow response (which will result in large output variations if the input changes rapidly). Electronic volume controls produce distortion and noise. 'Servo' control must be finely tuned to get fastest response without overshoot or instability. 'Feedforward' control has to be finely calibrated to get a constant output level. The circuit may be quite complex and need expensive components.

However these methods do have the advantage that the original waveform is (theoretically) accurately preserved, provided it doesn't change amplitude too fast. But what if you don't care about that and just want to output a pure sine wave with a fixed phase relationship to the input? There are a couple of ways to do this too:-

1. Amplify the signal until it is [limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiter) or use a [comparator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) to produce a square wave output, then remove the harmonics with a low pass filter so it becomes (almost) a pure sine wave again.
2. Feed the signal into a [Phase Locked Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) which controls the frequency of an oscillator. This has the advantage that the output will continue even if the input drops below detection level. However it may suffer from phase noise, and only have a relatively small 'lock-in' range where it follows the input frequency.

With these methods you are destroying the original waveform, or even generating a whole new waveform unrelated to the input. Is this cheating? Not if you don't need that information.

Which gets us to even simpler methods. If you don't care about reproducing the original waveform or phase, can handle a little distortion and frequency variation, and know what frequency is coming in, just use a sine wave oscillator set to the desired frequency and amplitude - and ignore the input altogether! Or perhaps you don't care about distortion either, so just create whatever waveform is easiest (triangle, square, sawtooth...).

"Ridiculous!", you say "It's perfectly obvious I didn't want that!".

But you didn't specify any tolerances for distortion or phase, or how it should respond to input amplitudes outside the specified range, or frequencies other than what it was made for (eg. 50 Hz). You only talked about a 'sinusoidal' wave, which implies that it doesn't have to work 'correctly' with any other waveform, and you said *nothing* about possible applications so we can't even guess what you *really* want.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic AGC or compressor/limiter application.

Essentially you need these building blocks:

1. a [Voltage Controlled Amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-gain_amplifier) (VCA) - an amplifier whose gain is controlled by a voltage. There are many ways of doing this, from dedicated ICs to op amp circuits using a FET as a voltage controlled resistor.
2. A circuit to rectify the output of the VCA and turn it into DC.
3. A feedback network which has the rectifer output at its input, the output of which controls the VCA. With correct design (which may require trial and error) this feedback will adjust the gain of the VCA such that its output remains more or less constant.

Some design requirements you need to think about as well:

1. Over what range of frequencies to you need this circuit to work?
2. What range of input amplitude do you need to handle (your VCA will have minimum and maximum gain which will need to be taken into account).
3. How much distortion is acceptable? VCAs themselves can introduce some distortion, also when the frequency is low the rectifier output may show some ripple from the input signal, which will cause some output distortion.
4. How quickly must the output amplitude amplitude react when there is a step change in input amplitude? This determines time constants in the rectifier and feedback circuit.

There are obviously a multitude of ways to implement such a circuit, and you do not provide enough information to be more specific, but this answer is intended to describe the general solution, and act as a start point for further investigation and thought.